# Deleting duplicate record from table - SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

I need to delete duplicate rows only from the table, like I have 3 duplicate rows in the table, my query will delete 2 rows from 3 duplicated rows.

How can I get this? Please help me.

Comment: @Matt - I saw what you did there :)

Comment: Heh, I guess it's open to interpretation, but the first sentence is imperative, so .. :)

Comment: This seems like an interview question. Which db, are there ids. Are you allowed to use temp tables?

Comment: u r absolutely right astander its an interview question, it cud b any DB and not allowed to use temp table

Comment: I don't think I'll answer since someone (presumably the OP) immediately votes all answers down!

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have posted my answer without more information, for instance, what makes a record duplicate!

Comment: A great way to encourage answers!

Comment: @Tony Andrews that was my guess. Hopefully this will be closed!

Comment: In fact, the question is unanswerable without knowing the specific DBMS: by definition, there is no way in general to distinguish between true duplicate rows in a table.  However, in practice most DBMSs provide a construct like Oracle's ROWID that gives a way to distinguish between otherwise duplicate rows.

Comment: @Tony Andrews You are correct, and when writing DELETE queries, everyone is usually very critical, as they are dangerous, and rightly so, I definitely deserved my -3 votes on my query, but again, I think it was due to the fact that I didn't know enough specifics.

Comment: The OP's not got enough rep to vote answers down

Comment: @Tony - At least in SQL Server ROWID doesn't work and neither does Row_Number...Over.  I assume that this is because the generated values are not actually placed on the underlying table.  You can *select* using them (and get only two rows) but you cannot *delete* using them.

Comment: Although the DBMS isn't specified, I think that it would be better to add answers that refer to the popular DBMSs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try the below query, it will definitely meet your objective

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
DELETE test
FROM test a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test b WHERE b.name = a.name) > 1
WHILE @@rowcount > 0
  DELETE test
  FROM test a
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test b WHERE b.name = a.name) > 1
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

where **test** is your table name

Comment: @Muhammad - you're right. I left a comment in Dor's answer to that effect as well.  This is the right answer as it doesn't assume anything "extra" in Santanu's question.  I am playing with this answer and have to admit that I have only a glimmer of why it works.  It uses ROWCOUNT and WHILE in ways that I just don't quite understand yet.  Always good to learn something new!  ...And I'm usually the one who gets the impossible answer on SQL Questions :-(

Comment: Mark, I think you should post this as an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: Ok - I get the WHILE now - it isn't linked (magically) to the Delete.  The SET ROWCOUNT 1 ensures that the following operations only apply to 1 ROW at a time rather than being fully set oriented. The Delete then deletes ONE row where there is a duplicate on the a.name.  The WHILE makes use of the resulting @@rowcount and starts a loop.  The loop dies when there are no more duplicates.  All cool. *However* - I still am working on the Delete TblName From TblName Where X construct...  It *is* required to make this work - just have to figure out why.

Comment: @Zoidberg - I will, along with an easier way to delete than found in Dor's answer.  I want to see Muhammad's anser get a few more upvotes though.  It is a *great* answer because it is forcing me to learn something new.

Comment: I thought @@rowcount was MSSQL, not across all dbs? MySQL has ROW_COUNT() instead, right? It's a quite nice bit of code, though

Comment: Now that Muhammad's answer is "accepted" - I provide my own, which does not require a loop.  In the end, I'd use mine (for reasons I indicate below) but *THIS* answer is why I surf StackOverflow: there are just so many really smart and experienced people here.

Comment: Muhammad - thanks again.  What I didn't get about the "Delete TblName From TblName A..." construct is that you have to identify the table from which you'd be deleting rows because your FROM clause renames the table ("A").  Also, your WHERE is, technically, operating on another table: the "b" version of the test table.

So, the delete could also be: DELETE FROM DupTable WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DupTable b WHERE b.Col1 = DupTable.Col1) > 1

Answer (score 4):

This works in SQL Server although it isn't a single statement:

```
Declare @cnt int; 
Select @cnt=COUNT(*) From DupTable Where (Col1=1);  -- Assumes you are trying to delete the duplicates where some condition (e.g. Col1=1) is true.
Delete Top (@cnt-1) From DupTable
```

It also doesn't require any *extra* assumptions (like the existance of another column that makes each row unique).  After all, Santanu did say that the *rows* were duplicates and not just the one column.

However, the **right** answer, in my view, is to get a real table structure.  That is, add an IDENTITY column to this table so that you can use a single SQL command to do your work.  Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DupTable ADD
    IDCol int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
GO
```

Then the delete is trivial:

```
DELETE FROM DupTable WHERE IDCol NOT IN 
   (SELECT MAX(IDCol) FROM DupTable GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM Table t1, Table t2 WHERE t1.colDup = t2.colDup AND t1.date < t2.date
```

Will delete every duplicate row from `Table` (on column `colDup`) except the oldest (i.e. lowset `date`).

Comment: The thing I don't like about this, is that it assumes there is one column that differentiates these duplicate rows, but given the amount of detail in this question...

Comment: You're quite right, but then again; "the amount of detail...".

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM `mytbl`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 FROM `mytbl`
        GROUP BY `duplicated_column` HAVING COUNT(*)=2
    ) USING(`id`)
```

Edit:

My bad, the above query won't work.

Assuming table structure:

`id` int auto_increment

`num` int  # <-- this is the column with duplicated values

The following query would work in MySQL (i checked):

```
DELETE `mytbl` FROM `mytbl` 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT `num` FROM `mytbl`
        GROUP BY `num` HAVING COUNT(*)=2
    ) AS `tmp` USING (`num`)
```

The query would delete the rows that have 2 (not more or else) duplicated values in the `num` column.

Edit (again):

I suggest to add a key on the `num` column.

Edit(#3):

In case that the author wanted to delete the duplicated *rows*, the following should work for MySQL (it worked for me):

```
DELETE `delete_duplicated_rows` FROM `delete_duplicated_rows`
    NATURAL JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM `delete_duplicated_rows`
        GROUP BY `num1` HAVING COUNT(*)=2
    ) AS `der`
```

While assuming table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `delete_duplicated_rows` (
  `num1` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
  `num2` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: I don't think that this solution actually follows the restrictions laid out in the problem, does it?  Santanu indicated that all *rows* were duplicates.  Having an IDENTITY column means that the rows aren't duplicates - and makes this a fairly easy problem.  Muhammad's answer is better.

Comment: @Mark Brittingham: You're correct! I've edit my answer and I've add another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the id's of the rows you want to delete then...

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 4, 7, [id numbers to delete...])
```

Comment: @Zoidberg his question says he has 3 duplicates and needs to delete two. If he knows the ID's then this is sufficient.

Comment: Again, question details are sketchy... so yeah, I can understand the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think each table has unique identifier.
So if it exists then you can write following query:
Delete Table1 from Table1 t1 where 2 >= (select count(id) from Table1 where dupColumn = t1.dupColumn) and 
t1.id not in (select max (id) from Table1 where dupColumn = t1.dupColumn)

OOps. It seems it is possible to use second filter only
Delete Table1 from Table1 t1 where 
t1.id not in (select max (id) from Table1 where dupColumn = t1.dupColumn)

Answer (score 1):

```
  -- Just to demonstrates Marks example          
    . 
        -- START === 1.0.dbo..DuplicatesTable.TableCreate.sql
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DuplicatesTable] 
        Script Date: 03/29/2010 21:24:02 ******/
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
     WHERE 
object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DuplicatesTable]') 
AND type in (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[DuplicatesTable]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DuplicatesTable]    
Script Date: 03/29/2010 21:24:02 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DuplicatesTable](
        [ColA] [varchar](10) NOT NULL, -- the name of the DuplicatesTable
        [ColB] [varchar](10) NULL,  -- the description of the e DuplicatesTable 
     ) 


    /* 
    <doc> 
    Models a DuplicatesTable for 
    </doc>

    */


    GO


    --============================================================ DuplicatesTable START
    declare @ScriptFileName varchar(2000)
    SELECT @ScriptFileName = '$(ScriptFileName)'
    SELECT @ScriptFileName + ' --- DuplicatesTable START =========================================' 
    declare @TableName varchar(200)
    select @TableName = 'DuplicatesTable'

    SELECT 'SELECT name from sys.tables where name =''' + @TableName + ''''
    SELECT name from sys.tables 
    where name = @TableName

    DECLARE @TableCount INT 
    SELECT @TableCount  = COUNT(name ) from sys.tables 
        where name =@TableName

    if @TableCount=1
    SELECT ' DuplicatesTable PASSED. The Table ' + @TableName + ' EXISTS ' 
    ELSE 
    SELECT ' DuplicatesTable FAILED. The Table ' + @TableName + ' DOES NOT EXIST ' 
    SELECT @ScriptFileName + ' --- DuplicatesTable END =========================================' 
    --============================================================ DuplicatesTable END

    GO


    -- END ===  1.0.dbo..DuplicatesTable.TableCreate.sql

    . 
    -- START === 1.1..dbo..DuplicatesTable.TableInsert.sql

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DuplicatesTable]([ColA], [ColB])
    SELECT   N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA', N'ColB' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1' UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'ColA1', N'ColB1'
    COMMIT;
    RAISERROR (N'[dbo].[DuplicatesTable]: Insert Batch: 1.....Done!', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    GO


    -- END ===  1.1..dbo..DuplicatesTable.TableInsert.sql

    . 
    -- START === 2.0.RemoveDuplicates.Script.sql
    ALTER TABLE dbo.DuplicatesTable ADD
            DuplicatesTableId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
    GO

    -- Then the delete is trivial:
    DELETE FROM dbo.DuplicatesTable WHERE DuplicatesTableId NOT IN 
         (SELECT MAX(DuplicatesTableId) FROM dbo.DuplicatesTable GROUP BY ColA , ColB)

         Select * from DuplicatesTable ;  
    -- END ===  2.0.RemoveDuplicates.Script.sql
```