# How Can I merge Duplicate row and Then delete all duplicate after keeping on row

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have Table in that there is 15th column i want to merge duplicate rows in one row and then delete that duplicate row after keeping one row as record

My Table like that

```
id name email address city state country salary ....
1   a    a@a.a null   null  a     xyx    null
2   null a@a.a a      a     null  null   10000
```

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748459/deleting-duplicate-record-from-table-sql-query/1748770#1748770

Answer (score 1):

You could group on `email` and update all columns with the groupwise maximum:

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(50), email varchar(50), 
     address varchar(50), city varchar(50), state varchar(50), 
     country varchar(50), salary int)
insert  @t
values  (1, 'a', 'a@a.a', null, null, 'a', 'xyx', null),
        (2, null, 'a@a.a', 'a', 'a', null, null, 10000)

-- Update all rows for an email address
update  t
set     name = combined.name
,       address = combined.address
,       city = combined.city
,       state = combined.state
,       country = combined.country
,       salary = combined.salary
from    @t t
join    (
        select
                max(name) as name
        ,       email
        ,       max(address) as address
        ,       max(city) as city
        ,       max(state) as state
        ,       max(country) as country
        ,       max(salary) as salary
        from    @t
        group by
                email
        ) combined
on      combined.email = t.email
```

Then delete all duplicate rows:

```
-- Delete duplicate rows
delete  t
from    @t t
join    @t t2
on      t2.email = t.email
        and t2.id < t.id

-- Display result
select * from @t
```

This prints:

```
id name email address city state country salary
1  a    a@a.a a       a    a     xyx     10000
```